# Qt QSqlDatabase QSQLITE driver not loaded error

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, qt, qsqldatabase

> I am getting the driver not loaded error when trying to open an sqlite
> database with Qt 5.15.0 on Windows.
> Here is my output: QSqlDatabase: QSQLITE driver not loaded QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QPSQL QPSQL7 QODBC QODBC3
> "Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"
>
> Here are the files in the directory with  my .exe (currently and for
> this output): main.o app.exe qrc_qml.cpp qrc_qml.o
>
> I have done some searches on this topic and they have suggested the
> following:
>
> 1. manually move the sqldrivers folder to the exe directory or try moving its contents to the directory, neither have resolved my issue,
>    output remains the same
> 2. use windeployqt.  I have tried this but despite it moving the dlls including moving the sqldrivers folder to the exe directory, the same
>    error appears
>
> Please let me know what you suggest

```
QSqlDatabase my_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
my_db.setDatabaseName("test.db");

if(my_db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "open";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << my_db.lastError().text();
}
```

Comment: Can you send the directory from where you are copying qsqlite.dll?

Comment: Did you remember to add QT += sql to your .pro file? Do you get the same issue if you use one of the complete sqlite code examples included in Qt docs/examples?

Comment: I am facing the same issue under Linux. It should work in theory, but it does not. In my case I did set `QT += sql`.